# Rails nested routes for devise user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

Hello I have an issue with my routing. I currently have devise user with a nested post resource. Currently I am trying to be able to create a new post for each user.

*routes.rb*

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  root 'home#index'

  resources :dashboard

  devise_for :users, :path => '', :path_names => {
    :sign_in => 'login',
    :sign_out => 'logout',
    :sign_up => 'register'
  }

  resource :users do
    resources :posts
  end
end
```

*posts_controller.rb*

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_user

  def index
    @posts = @user.posts
  end

  def new
    @post = @user.posts.new
  end

  def create
    @post = @user.posts.new(post_params)
    if @post.save
      redirect_to :controller => 'dashboard', :action => 'index'
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

private

  def post_params

  end

  def set_user
    @user = current_user
  end
end
```

*link*

```
<%= button_to "New Post", new_users_post_path(current_user), :class => "btn btn-default navbar-btn", :method =>  :get  %>
```

*route*

```
   new_users_post GET    /users/posts/new(.:format)      posts#new
```

This leads to:
NoMethodError at /users/posts/new
undefined method `user_posts_path' for #<#:0x007fe01d1608f0>. Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't resolve problem, but `new_users_post_path` should be without any params:

```
<%= button_to "New Post", new_users_post_path, class: "btn btn-default navbar-btn", method:  :get  %>
```

also `resource :user` instead `users`

Comment: Thanks! But I am still getting the same error. (undefined method `user_posts_path' for #<#<Class:0x007fe01d1f77c8>:0x007fe01d0339f0>)